# GWT and SOAP classes

Tags: java, gwt, soap

I have a Web Server which uses SOAP to communicate with a several resources.

I'm using pure JavaScript for the Web App interface. There are allot of data changing between the client and server which includes classes returned by SOAP requests.

I use GSON to create JSON objects from the SOAP responses (which can be all sorts of custom classes) and in JavaScript and just need to access the JSON fields.

Now I was thinking about using GWT on the client but started to have some doubts when planning the implementation.

If I use GWT all the classes generated for the SOAP interface must be accessible to the GWT compiler as I wont be using JSON but the classes directly through Assync Requests.

Now the problem is that there are allot of possible versions of this classes depending on the resource software version itself.

If I continue to use JavaScript that's not a very strong issue because the JSON encoded by the Server using GSON can be of any kind and if it doesn't have a particular attribute that's ok due to JavaScript type free nature (I can just check JsonSoapResponse.field22 != undefined).

If I use GWT will I need to have as much class versions as there are in the server side?

I thought about using JavaScript Overlay types but won't that require rewriting almost all SOAP classes to extend JavaScriptObject and expose their methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a look at the AutoBean mechanism.

You will not beed JavaScript Overlay types anymore, just interfaces and the GWT Compiler will do the rest.

see: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/AutoBean